# Huffman storing code in bits

Tags: c++

I have build the huffman tree. But I have no idea to store the code to bits due to I don't know how

to handle the variable length.

I want to create a table that store the huffman code in bits for print the encoded result.

I cannot use the STL containter like bitset.

I have try like that

```
   void traverse( string code = "")const
   {
        if( frequency == 0 ) return;
        if ( left ) {
             left->traverse( code + '0' );
             right->traverse( code + '1' );
        }
        else {//leaf node
             huffmanTable[ch] = code;
        }
   }
```

Can you give me some algorithm to handle it?

**I want to store the '0' use 1 bit and "1" use 1 bit.**

Thx in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you pasted above using a string to hold the bit pattern?

Comment: Oh I want to store it in bits, and I don't know how to use because I don't know the exact length.

Comment: A bit is just a value that can only be a zero or a one. A string that consists of only zeroes and ones is a string of bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a buffer, a variable to track the size of the buffer in bytes, and a variable to track the number of valid bits in the buffer.

To store a bit:

1. Check if adding a bit will increase the number of bytes stored. If not, skip to step 4.
2. Is there room in the buffer to store an additional byte? If so, skip to step 4.
3. Reallocate a storage buffer a few bytes larger. Copy the existing data. Increase the variable holding the size of the buffer.
4. Compute the byte position and bit position at which the next bit will be stored. Set or clear that bit as appropriate.
5. Increment the variable holding the number of bits stored.

Comment: Before reimplementing this, I'd suggest having a look at `std::vector<bool>`, which should essentially do what you've suggested.

Comment: It does! It's up to the implementation you're using, but it's usually implemented in a way that 8 vector entries are stored within one byte (i.e. 1 bit per bit of information). (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fixed size structure to store the table and just bits to store encoded input:

```
struct TableEntry {
  uint8_t size;
  uint8_t code;
};

TableEntry huffmanTable[256];

void traverse(uint8_t size; uint8_t code) const {
        if( frequency == 0 ) return;
        if ( left ) {
             left->traverse(size+1, code << 1 );
             right->traverse(size+1, (code << 1) | 1 );
        }
        else {//leaf node
             huffmanTable[ch].code = code;
             huffmanTable[ch].size = size;
        }
}
```

For encoding, you can use the algorithm posted by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811470/390913).

Comment: Might be wrong there, but shouldn't you set/mention a default value of `1` for `code`? Otherwise you can't determine how often you've used the `left` node (e.g. 5 times left + 1 right vs. 3 times left + 1 right).

Comment: Yes, should do it, although it's not very effective depending on your maximum size/depth/length as it's 1 bit vs. the size of `uint8_t`.

Comment: Yes, but I think the table size is not really important.

Comment: Hm... really depends. :) After all we're trying to compress data, so doubling the code size might not be the best idea.

Comment: Then you can use `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` depending on your need. In the worst case, you can use a fixed sized array of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I'd use one of two different approaches here, based on the maximum key length/depth of the tree:

- If you've got a fixed length and it's shorter than your available integer data types (like `long int`), you can use the approach shown by perreal.
- If you don't know the maximum depth and think you might be running out of space, I'd use `std::vector<bool>` as the code value. This is a special implementation of the vector using a single bit per value (essentially David's approach).